# Keep a record of changes in spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

Good morning

I would like to ask for your help, to see if this is possible to do.
I want to make a spreadsheet file where I can keep an inventory of equipment.
Every change you make, I want a second sheet to show the copy of that line and the date it was changed.

Do you see this possible?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the function code in the script editor to append a row in another sheet adding the timestamp and the changed value.

Also, these function can be triggered on onEdit(e) event of the spreadsheet.

The Following articles can help you for this.

[Trigger Reference Article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

[SpreadsheetApp Reference Article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your answer. I'm quite newbie in this (in fact i haven't seen anything of this).

I checked the articles you send me but I don't understand what to do with that.

Can you give me and example of how it should be the code based on a sheet?

Thank you